# Laptop turning Off randomly without warning

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, shutdown, gpu, amd-radeon

I have HP dv6 pavilion laptop, it is turning off suddenly and randomly without any warning.what I have tried:

1. Checked for heat issue and cleaned up the fan and replaced the sink paste too.
2. checked for CMOS battery, it is working fine.
3. Checked CPU temperature.It is about 50-60 degree celcius.
4. I have two GPUs intel and AMD, I tried many applications but no one showing AMD card temperature and other sensor features.
   Sometimes it doesn't turn on too, I need to take battery out and insert that and again take it out and insert again to turn the laptop on.
   [Psensor results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NNyx.jpg)
5. [AMD system monitor result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B9Zd.jpg)
6. [GPU-Z AMD card details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67lPc.jpg)
7. [GPU-Z AMD sensor card details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGYCn.jpg)
8. [Resource and perfmon details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSKFM.png)
9. [Event Viewer Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmcKy.png)

I want to ask whether my AMD card is faulty or not? I think AMD is my discrete card whereas intel is integrated card. What can be other possibilities for unexpected and random shut downs of PC?

Comment: Take a look at the time the machine shuts down next time. When it boots back up check the event viewer (Application and System) for events prior. It may indicate the issue. Also, when you say the machine doesn't 'turn on' what happens when you push the power button?

Comment: @Stese it says unexpected shutdown. Yes, I mean turn on means by pushing power button.I checked even viewer it says unexpected shutdown.

Comment: unexpected shutdown would be after the fact... have a look for any warnings or errors before.

Comment: No errors whatsoever, nor warnings.